# Is it possible to simulate/emulate some of the unusual situations when testing an in-app purchase?

Tags: ios, testing, in-app-purchase

I am looking to test our in-app purchasing code and would like to be able to test all the different possible situations. However, it seems like it is difficult/impossible to test some of the rarer cases that sometimes happen.

I know that with iOS6 I can simulate a bad network connection, but there must be other situations that might cause a failure. For example,

1. If the user needs to verify their payment method (for example, because they are using a new credit card or they are purchasing on a device for the first time). As far as I know, there is no way to test this situation in the Sandbox environment.
2. A failed transaction inside the app (I guess this could be simulated through bad network simulation)
3. Being in the wrong app store:

   3.1. perhaps the in-app purchase is not available in the user's app store or,

   3.2. the user needs to switch app store

I would be very grateful if anyone had some solid methods to test some of these scenarios (and any others I have not written above). It seems some of these are not testable until you are in the production environment.

References:

- [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/in-app-purchase/index.html)
- [Sandbox: Is possible to simulate a failed or interrupted In App Purchase?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12836387/377384)
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/12089490/377384
- [iPhone - in-app purchase testing for failure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6720616/377384)